# Unable to make Google Analytics filter work

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics

I wish to create a custom filter on Google Analytics (GA), that would allow me to block all views except the genuine ones onto my webpage.

I want to do this because the google-analytics ID associated with my property (UA-XXXXXXXX-X) is public. Hence in theory, my analytics data is open to attack.

I was trying to follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419250/is-sharing-google-analytics-tracking-id-safe). As suggested I created a custom filter to *exclude* any hits from `Hostnames` other than my webpage (or any sub-webpages) - `https://ishank-juneja.github.io/`. In particular the steps I followed were -

`New filter --> custom -->  include --> Choose filter field as Hostname`

Then I entered the filter pattern as `https://ishank-juneja\.github\.io/`. Which I believe is the correct regex corresponding to my site URL/Hostname.

I thought this would be enough to make the filter work, however to be sure, I changed the filter type to *exclude* instead of *include*, expecting that if the configuration is correct this filter would start rejecting hits from the url `https://ishank-juneja.github.io/` and any of its sub-pages.

However when I clicked the filter verification button available at the bottom of the create-filter page, I received the message-

> "This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."

Since I am certain that all my earlier hits were from the mentioned url, it seems that the filter is not configured correctly even in the *include* mode.

Any help in correcting the working of the filter, so that only hits from the desired Hostname are recorded, would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should also use a `\ ` before any `/` and maybe before `:` -HTH ;).

Comment: @shA.t Thank you for the help, the answer below solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this regex for hostname (without protocol and trailing slash):

```
ishank-juneja\.github\.io
```

Comment: I have another property/url that I wanted to do the same with `http://home.iitb.ac.in/~name/`. Going by your answer which worked for the earlier case, I tried using `home\.iitb\.ac\.in/~name` and `home\.iitb\.ac\.in\/~name` but neither of them worked. Could you tell me what to do here?

Comment: This part is not a part of an host name: ~name. So just remove it from filter.

Comment: Ok but then I would still potentially get views from `home.iitb.ac.in/~otherName` right?

Comment: Yes, you filter the URL based its hostname

Comment: Can I create some other filter that would block `home.iitb.ac.in/otherName` type URLs too?

Comment: You have to set another filter based page path.