# Can/should I hide my Google Analytics Measurement ID in the site config

Tags: asp.net-core, google-analytics

I need to add the latest Google Analytics (GA4) script to a site, for the business.

[image]
It is an ASP.NET Core MVC webapp so it's going in the _layout page.

There a few potential issues I see with the Measurement ID:

- It is visible to the public via the page source (so anyone could track the stats)
- It would require a code change if the production ID needs to change
- There is no difference between IDs for the development vs production environment

[image]

My question(s) is:

- In general is it worth putting the Measurement ID in to a config to alleviate the above conerns?
- What would the best practice way of achieving this e.g. appsettings.json, user secret?

Many thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419250/is-sharing-google-analytics-tracking-id-safe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is sharing Google Analytics tracking id safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49419250/is-sharing-google-analytics-tracking-id-safe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general scenarios, you could try to save it in the `appsettings.json` file. For storing sensitive data, I would suggest you use [Azure Key Vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/basic-concepts).

For more detailed information, you could refer to this [helpful article](https://stormpath.com/blog/store-protect-sensitive-data-dotnet-core).